# Three.js missing shadowCamera

Tags: javascript, three.js, shadow

I am currently learning Three.js and I am trying out this demo:

```
function init(){
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, .1, 500);
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

  renderer.setClearColor(0xdddddd);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
  renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;

  //Enable orbit controls
  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.addEventListener('change', render);

  var axis = new THREE.AxisHelper(10);
  scene.add(axis);

  var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(50, 5);
  var color = new THREE.Color("rgb(255,0,0)");
  grid.setColors(color, 0x000000);
  scene.add(grid);

  var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 5, 5);
  var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xff3300});
  var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);

  cube.position.x = 2.5;
  cube.position.y = 4;
  cube.position.z = 2.5;
  cube.castShadow = true;
  scene.add(cube);

  camera.position.x = 40;
  camera.position.y = 40;
  camera.position.z = 40;

  camera.lookAt(scene.position);

  var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(30, 30, 30);
  var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff});
  var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);

  plane.rotation.x = -.5*Math.PI;
  plane.recieveShadow = true;
  scene.add(plane);

  var guiControls = new function(){
    this.rotationX = 0.01;
    this.rotationY = 0.01;
    this.rotationZ = 0.01;

    this.lightX = 20;
    this.lightY = 35;
    this.lightZ = 40;
    this.intensity = 1;
    this.distance = 0;
    this.angle = 1.570;
    this.exponent = 0;
    this.shadowCameraNear = 10;
    this.shadowCameraFar = 100;
    this.shadowCameraFov = 50;
    this.shadowCameraVisible = true;
    this.shadowMapWidht = 1028;
    this.shadowMapHeight = 1020;
    this.shadowBias = 0.01;
    this.shadowDarkness = 0.5;
  }

  var spotlight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
  spotlight.castShadow = true;
  spotlight.position.set(20, 35, 40);
  spotlight.intensity = guiControls.intensity;
  spotlight.distance = guiControls.distance;
  spotlight.angle = guiControls.angle;
  spotlight.exponent = guiControls.exponent;
  spotlight.shadowCameraNear = guiControls.shadowCameraNear;
  spotlight.shadowCameraFar = guiControls.shadowCameraFar;
  spotlight.shadowCameraFov = guiControls.shadowCameraFov;
  spotlight.shadowCameraVisible = guiControls.shadowCameraVisible;
  spotlight.shadowBias = guiControls.shadowBias;
  spotlight.shadowDarkness = guiControls.shadowDarkness;

  scene.add(spotlight);

  var datGUI = new dat.GUI();
  datGUI.add(guiControls, 'rotationX', 0, 1);
  datGUI.add(guiControls, 'rotationY', 0, 1);
  datGUI.add(guiControls, 'rotationZ', 0, 1);
  datGUI.add(guiControls, 'lightX', -60, 180);
  datGUI.add(guiControls, 'lightY', 0, 180);
  datGUI.add(guiControls, 'lightZ', -60, 180);

  datGUI.add(guiControls, 'intensity', 0.01, 5).onChange(function(value){
    spotlight.intensity = value;
  });
  datGUI.add(guiControls, 'distance', 0, 1000).onChange(function(value){
    spotlight.distance = value;
  });
  datGUI.add(guiControls, 'angle', 0.001, 1.570).onChange(function(value){
    spotlight.angle = value;
  });
  datGUI.add(guiControls, 'exponent', 0, 50).onChange(function(value){
    spotlight.exponent = value;
  });
  datGUI.add(guiControls, 'shadowCameraNear', 0, 100).name('Near').onChange(function(value){
    spotlight.shadowCameraNear = value;
    spotlight.shadowCamera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  });
  datGUI.add(guiControls, 'shadowCameraFar', 0, 5000).name('Far').onChange(function(value){
    spotlight.shadowcameraFar = value;
    spotlight.shadowCamera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  });
  datGUI.add(guiControls, 'shadowCameraFov', 0, 180).name('Fov').onChange(function(value){
    spotlight.shadowcameraFov = value;
    spotlight.shadowCamera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  });
  datGUI.add(guiControls, 'shadowCameraVisible').onChange(function(value){
    spotlight.shadowcameraVisible = value;
    spotlight.shadowCamera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  });
  datGUI.add(guiControls, 'shadowBias', 0, 1).onChange(function(value){
    spotlight.shadowBias = value;
    spotlight.shadowCamera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  });
  datGUI.add(guiControls, 'shadowDarkness', 0, 1).onChange(function(value){
    spotlight.shadowDarkness = value;
    spotlight.shadowCamera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  });


  var container = document.getElementById("webglcontainer");
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement );

  //Add stats
  var stats = new Stats();
  stats.domElement.style.position = "absolute";
  stats.domElement.style.left = "0px";
  stats.domElement.style.top = "0px";

  container.appendChild(stats.domElement);

  function render() {
    cube.rotation.x = guiControls.rotationX;
    cube.rotation.y = guiControls.rotationY;
    cube.rotation.z = guiControls.rotationZ;

    spotlight.position.x = guiControls.lightX;
    spotlight.position.y = guiControls.lightY;
    spotlight.position.z = guiControls.lightZ;
  }

  function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
    stats.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }

  animate();
}
init();
```

The thing is I cannot seem to make the shadow camera to appear. The light is visible, I can manipulate it, but the cube is not casting any shadows on the plane below it...

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ```plane.recieveShadow``` -> ```plane.receiveShadow```

Comment: I feel so stupid... Haven`t gotten used to javascript yet (php dev here). Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am glad this already did it for you, but I hate solved stackoverflow questions that arent marked as such :-)

So Im reposting the solution that it was just a spelling error in `plane.receiveShadow = true;`.

It looks like the code is based on [this example](http://wpdildine.github.io/blog/2015/03/31/Lighting-Properties-in-THREE.js/) (where it is spelled correctly) and may be of interest for someone to learn about lighting.